# Image capture at QSXGA resolution by OV5640 in ESP32s3

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32-s3

```
// Include necessary libraries
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "soc/soc.h"           // Disable brownout problems
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"  // Disable brownout problems
#include "driver/rtc_io.h"
#include <SPIFFS.h>
#include <FS.h>
#include <Firebase_ESP_Client.h>
#include <addons/TokenHelper.h>
//#include <ArduinoJson.h>      // JSON library

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "PASSSS";


// Replace with your Firebase project details
#define API_KEY "API"
#define USER_EMAIL "EIMAI@gmail.com"
#define USER_PASSWORD "PASS"
#define STORAGE_BUCKET_ID "esp32cam-AAA.appspot.com"
#define FILE_PHOTO "/photo.jpg"

#define CAMERA_MODEL_ESP_EYE  // Has PSRAM
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM -1
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM 15
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM 4
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM 5
#define Y9_GPIO_NUM 16
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM 17
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM 18
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM 12
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM 10
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM 8
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM 9
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM 11
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM 6
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM 7
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM 13

// Flags and variables
boolean takeNewPhoto = true;
FirebaseData fbdo;
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseConfig configF;
bool taskCompleted = false;

void initCamera() {
  // OV2640 camera module
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sccb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sccb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_QSXGA;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;  // for streaming
  //config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_RGB565; // for face detection/recognition
  config.grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_WHEN_EMPTY;
  config.fb_location = CAMERA_FB_IN_PSRAM;
  config.jpeg_quality = 12;
  config.fb_count = 1;

  // if PSRAM IC present, init with UXGA resolution and higher JPEG quality
  //                      for larger pre-allocated frame buffer.
  if (config.pixel_format == PIXFORMAT_JPEG) {
    if (psramFound()) {
      config.jpeg_quality = 10;
      config.fb_count = 2;
      config.grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_LATEST;
    } else {
      // Limit the frame size when PSRAM is not available
      config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
      config.fb_location = CAMERA_FB_IN_DRAM;
    }
  } else {
    // Best option for face detection/recognition
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_240X240;
#if CONFIG_IDF_TARGET_ESP32S3
    config.fb_count = 2;
#endif
  }

#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_ESP_EYE)
  pinMode(13, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(14, INPUT_PULLUP);
#endif

  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }

  sensor_t* s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  // initial sensors are flipped vertically and colors are a bit saturated
  if (s->id.PID == OV3660_PID) {
    s->set_vflip(s, 1);        // flip it back
    s->set_brightness(s, 1);   // up the brightness just a bit
    s->set_saturation(s, -2);  // lower the saturation
  }
  // drop down frame size for higher initial frame rate
  if (config.pixel_format == PIXFORMAT_JPEG) {
    // s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_QVGA);
    s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_XGA);
    Serial.println("Frame UXGA..");

  }

#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_WIDE) || defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_ESP32CAM)
  s->set_vflip(s, 1);
  s->set_hmirror(s, 1);
#endif

#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_ESP32S3_EYE)
  s->set_vflip(s, 1);
#endif

// Setup LED FLash if LED pin is defined in camera_pins.h
#if defined(LED_GPIO_NUM)
  setupLedFlash(LED_GPIO_NUM);
#endif
}

// Initialize WiFi connection
void initWiFi() {
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi...");
}

// Check if photo file is valid
bool checkPhoto(fs::FS& fs) {
  File f_pic = fs.open(FILE_PHOTO);
  unsigned int pic_sz = f_pic.size();
  return (pic_sz > 100);
}

// Initialize SPIFFS file system
void initSPIFFS() {
  if (!SPIFFS.begin(true)) {
    Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
    ESP.restart();
  } else {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("SPIFFS mounted successfully");
  }
}

// Initialize camera
void capturePhotoSaveSpiffs() {
  camera_fb_t* fb = NULL;
  bool ok = false;

  Serial.println("Taking a photo...");
  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if (!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    return;
  }

  Serial.printf("Picture file name: %s\n", FILE_PHOTO);
  File file = SPIFFS.open(FILE_PHOTO, FILE_WRITE);
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file in writing mode");
  } else {
    file.write(fb->buf, fb->len);
    Serial.print("The picture has been saved in ");
    Serial.print(FILE_PHOTO);
    Serial.print(" - Size: ");
    Serial.print(file.size());
    Serial.println(" bytes");
  }
  file.close();
  esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
  //ok = checkPhoto(SPIFFS);
  File imageFile = SPIFFS.open(FILE_PHOTO, FILE_READ);
  if (imageFile) {
    //if (Firebase.ready() && !taskCompleted) {
    // taskCompleted = true;
    Serial.println("Uploading picture...");

    if (Firebase.Storage.upload(&fbdo, STORAGE_BUCKET_ID, FILE_PHOTO, mem_storage_type_flash, FILE_PHOTO, "image/jpeg")) {
      Serial.printf("Download URL: %s\n", fbdo.downloadURL().c_str());
    } else {
      Serial.println(fbdo.errorReason());
    }
  }
  // } else {
  //   Serial.println("Failed to open image file in reading mode");
  // }
  imageFile.close();
  SPIFFS.remove(FILE_PHOTO);  // Remove image after upload
}

// Setup function
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  initWiFi();
  initSPIFFS();
  initCamera();
  configF.api_key = API_KEY;
  auth.user.email = USER_EMAIL;
  auth.user.password = USER_PASSWORD;
  Firebase.begin(&configF, &auth);
  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
}

// Main loop
void loop() {
  if (takeNewPhoto) {
    capturePhotoSaveSpiffs();
    takeNewPhoto = false;
  }
  delay(1);
}
```

How to set image resolution at QSXGA level by OV5640 camera in ESP32S3 module. Everything is working for low resolution but if going to highest resolution it is not working